# background color to drop down using css

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a code where i give the background color of blue in a drop down box using css.

The code i have written gives me the color over the TEXT rather than the whole territory of that specific line. Due to this Words which are longer show a bigger blue background color compared to their smaller counterparts.

Html goes as below

```
<div>
<span style="font-weight:bold;">Name</span><span type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#demo" ></span>
<span class="dropdown" id="demo">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#/account">My Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/referral">My Referrals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/payment">My Payments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/impersonation">Impersonate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/logout" >Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</span>
</div>
```

Sample css goes as below

```
#demo >.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
#demo > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus{

 background-color:#37c6f5;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

this code changes the background color of the text. I want each word to have the same background color length irrespective of the length of the word.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Would you please put your html code here as well.

Comment: added the sample part of the html code too

Comment: The code is not complete, I think you probably use some JS. But with given information. I think you can use some css for your li to change the background and remove the the background-color property from your current css. Something like this: `#demo >.dropdown-menu > li:hover,
#demo > .dropdown-menu > li:focus{
 background-color:#37c6f5;
}
#demo > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
#demo > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}`

Comment: yes i was using boot strap classes. I have managed to add extra &nbsp; to the code which increased the background colour for the words. I dont like the method but it works for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: block;` with href tag. For example

```
#demo >.dropdown-menu > li > a{
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this didn't change anything